# How do I get "get-iplayer" to use an already installed ffmpeg?

Tags: terminal, install

I'm following [these instructions](https://github.com/get-iplayer/get_iplayer/wiki/osx) (scroll down to "Manual Installation") to manually install get-iplayer Terminal command (don't want to use brew):

I see that this requires (and talks you through--partly) the install of ffmpeg and AtomicParsley.

I already installed ffmpeg weeks ago for another purpose so I really don't want another install of ffmpeg if I can do without it. (Can I?)

How can I proceed without installing another copy of ffmpeg?

Comment: Why don't you want to use brew? Seems like the easy way to do this. Also the questions you are asking are not really related to your original question. The questions you are asking are more or less related to command line concepts and brew is a command line software repository. So I can understand your confusion, but the really ironic thing is using brew (or the command line) for your task is going to so much easier in terms of actual steps. Using brew will save you tons of headaches in the command line that you are surly going to encounter using noted manual installation,

Comment: Isn‘t this more about installing get-iplayer and its dependencies than about ffmpeg? You‘ll get better answers if you focus on a specific problem, currently the question is rather broad. And as already been pointed out, ffmpeg as sich can easily get installed through brew

Comment: thanks for your input. I've got everything but ffmpeg installed. That's really my only question: do I need another copy dedicated to get-iplayer / can I just point to the existing one? Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I would reccomend installing [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and running `brew install ffmpeg`. That way you can delete the other one, because Homebrew installs it in /usr/local/bin so you won't have to worry about path issues.

**To install from the source you've already got:**
From [this page:](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/macOS)

`cd ~/Downloads/ffmpeg` to go to the FFMPEG directory

`./configure` along with your needed flags. You probably won't need anything additionally for what you're doing.

`make` and then `sudo make install`. Be sure to type your admin password.

Comment: Thanks for your input. My question is how to complete this install of ffmpeg. If you can answer that I'd be a happy chappy. Cheers.

Comment: Oh, you've already got a source folder. Ok, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Where is your ffmpeg install? You can check by running `whereis ffmpeg` to see if it is in a $PATH directory.